# Проблемы с кодировкой при парсинге сайта (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить информацию с сайта госзакупок. Споткунулся на первом же этапе - сама страница выдает абракадабру:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import bs4

def get_page(keyword, page_number):
    link = f'http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/extendedsearch/results.html?searchString={keyword}&morphology=on&openMode=USE_DEFAULT_PARAMS&pageNumber={page_number}&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_10&showLotsInfoHidden=false&fz44=on&fz223=on&fz94=on&pc=on&currencyIdGeneral=-1&publishDateFrom=01.01.2017&publishDateTo=31.12.2018&updateDateTo=29.05.2019&region_regions_5277343=region_regions_5277343&regions=5277343&regionDeleted=false&sortBy=UPDATE_DATE&exclText=проект+коммунальный+ТКО+ТБО+бытовой+норматив+разработка+поставка+реконструкция+сточный+дезинфекция+обучение+персонал+радиоактивный+ремонт'
    return link

page = requests.get(get_page('отход', 1)).text
soup = BS(page, from_encoding='UTF-8')

print(soup.title)
```

```
out:
<title> Ð¡ÑÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ° Ð½Ðµ Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ð´ÐµÐ½Ð° </title>
```

Буду рад подсказке чем нужно дополнить код. 
На самой странице в голове кодировка указана недвусмысленно:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
page = requests.get(get_page('отход', 1))
page.encoding = 'utf8'
htmlString = page.text
```